# What is special about boolean?

Tags: ruby, boolean, naming-conventions

In Ruby, there is a convention to have a method name end with a question mark to indicate that its return value is boolean. Why is boolean considered so special? Is there anything convenient if you know that a method's return value is particularly boolean? After all, in Ruby, you can insert all kinds of value returning (getter) methods into a conditional without caring whether it is boolean or not.

I think it is a waste to use the question mark just for indicating a boolean value. There should be more useful uses. I have plenty of use case where I want to have a pair of getter and setter methods, where the setter method should return `self` so that I can use it in a method chain. And naming them something like `get_foo` and `set_foo` looks cumbersome. Rather than following the convention, I am tempted to name a pair of getter and setter methods like this:

```
def foo?; @foo end
def foo v; @foo = v end
```

where the value of `@foo` is not (necessarily) boolean. (Besides potential criticism that breaking the convention will confuse other programmers), is there something wrong with doing that?

Comment: It's just a matter of convention. In other languages you'd write "isFoo" (which also implies a boolean), so "foo?" saves you a whole whopping character.

Comment: @Chris My point is why you need to indicate that something is a boolean in the first place. I think that distinguishing a getter and a setter method is much more important, and having a pair of such is more frequent than having a pair of methods with one returning a boolean and other a non-boolean, where you want to distinguish them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special at all, it's just a convention. A question can be answered with "yes" or "no", but also with another stuff like someone's name.

By returning a boolean on methods with a question mark, it indicates it to be an explicit behavior.

If you make the answer be "yes" or "no", it's easy for the reader of your code to identify the behavior of your method without even looking at the implementation. On the other hand, if you make it return any other type, it is more difficult for the reader to understand your code without reading your class and method definition.

With a boolean there are only two possible answers. If the return value is not boolean it can be anything, which would not help at all. You would still need to look at the method implementation. You should always look further to understand some piece of code, but using this convention makes it simpler.

Comment: Why do you need to save your time reading the document just when the value is boolean? For other methods, you have to know what it does. I am asking what is special about boolean. For example, if there were a convention to append a method name with some other character when it is a numeral, then you would not need to look up the document for such methods. Why is it not done for numerals but for boolean?

Comment: @sawa: see my answer. Question mark means "This method is a predicate and its result *should be treated* as true/false value". It does not dictate the return type.

Comment: Because with boolean there is only 2 possible answers. If not a boolean answer, it can be anything, which would not help at all. You would still need to look at the method implementation. 

You should always look further to understand some piece of code, but by doing this convention, it turns to make it simple to do.

Comment: @PauloHenrique I think your comment above is the real answer to my question. I don't think your answer as is now answers my question, but I am rather more convinced with your comment.

Answer (score 4):

There is a convention to use question mark in method names to indicate that a method is a predicate. AFAIK, this predicate is not required (by the convention) to return a boolean value, thanks to simple rules for truthy/falsey values.

> Besides potential criticism that breaking the convention will confuse other programmers, is there something wrong with doing that?

Confusing and surprising fellow programmers is bad. Ruby couldn't care less. It's just a convention. And conventions exist for a reason.

Comment: In OOP, any method is a predicate. I don't get why you say so just for methods with question mark. Or, are you mentioning the narrow sense of "predicate", which means that you are saying there is nothing wrong with doing as I wrote (besides your point in the second paragraph)?

Comment: What do you mean, "in OOP any method is a predicate"?

Comment: In OOP, methods are defined on the receiver. It is comparable to, say English, where you can have a sentence "John ate supper" with "John" the subject and "ate" the predicate. In that sense, in OOP, any method is predicated of the receiver. Isn't that what you meant?

Comment: No, he means mathematical definition of [predicate](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)), not the grammatical one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the pointer. Okay, now I think Sergio meant predicate as used in extensional logic. But I don't get the connection to the sentence following it. Is it saying that a method with a question mark indeed does not need to return a boolean?

Comment: It means that *all* objects in Ruby can be used as booleans, therefore you don't necessarily *have* to return `true` or `false`, you can also return anything else that evaluates to `true` or `false`. So, the question mark does not *guarantee* that the return value will be *exactly* one of the two objects `true` or `false`, it only means that the method is *intended* to be used as a predicate with a boolean return value. The `defined?` operator is a good example. It actually returns `nil` for undefined and a string with further information (such as `'local-variable'` or `'method'`) for defined.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* put anything in a flow control construct, but semantically booleans are appropriate. "If" in real human language typically takes a boolean, and the same is true of the construct in many programming languages. Ruby likes to make things convenient and assigns a "truthiness" value to everything in the language, which affects how it behaves in a boolean context.

In other words, booleans are the only things that are almost exclusively used for flow control, so the convention is to make them look "right" for flow-control constructs. It's their native environment.

> (Besides potential criticism that breaking the convention will confuse other programmers), is there something wrong with doing that?

In the same sense that there is nothing wrong with naming all your variables after 1920s comedians, no, there's nothing wrong with that. But also in the same sense as naming all your variables after 1920s comedians, it isn't a very good idea. Nowhere in any language that I know of -- human or computer -- does the question mark mean "get." So the semantics of your code are off with that convention.

Comment: I think your description about human languages is wrong. The primary purpose of the question mark in natural language is to ask a question, which is not necessary a yes-no (boolean) question. If you ask a question: "Your name" with a rising tone, it would be a question seeking your name, and that would be usually transcribed as "Your name?". And I think it is natural to extend that use of the question mark to computer languages.

Answer (score 2):

This question and the answers boil down to "POLS" AKA "[Principle of Least Surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_surprise)".

A method name can be a random choice of letters and numbers separated by underscores, with '!', '?' and '=' sprinkled through them, if we chose to do so. They could be randomly created by the code at run time, and, as long as the rest of the code used the same arrangement of characters, the program would run and Ruby would be happy.

We humans, the programmers, determine the name of the methods used, to represent something, a characteristic or an action. Trying to use randomly named methods would lead to madness, or at least a very hard to maintain program. So, instead, we try to use sensible names for things. Sometimes they're verbs or adjectives, sometimes they're more descriptive because the method does several things.

As part of that naming, sometimes we want to provide additional hints about the behavior of the method. By convention in Ruby, we use "!" to warn the coder that the method changes something or is destructive. "=" indicates the method takes a parameter and assigns it to the receiver/object. It's a setter method and in many other languages it'd be idiomatic to use "set_flag..." or "set_value..." as the name. It's just a convention in that language, and followed by developers in the language.

We use "?" in Ruby to ask a question about an object, whether it is, or isn't, true about that object. We could say "is_true?" or "true?" and indicate we are testing whether something is true about it. If it's true, or false, it's a Boolean response so we return a true/false value.

Comment: I don't understand how randomly naming a method is related to my question.